# psycopg2 change schema does not work

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.4, rds

I am writing a simple python prog to connect and display results from Postgres table this is on AWS RDS. I have table mytest in public schema.

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(dbname='some_test',
                    user='user1',
                    host='localhost',
                    password='userpwd',
                    port=postgres_port)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SET SEARCH_PATH TO public;")
cursor.execute("SELECT *  FROM mytest;")
```

But this throws an error

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "mytest" does not exist
>
> LINE 1: SELECT *  FROM mytest;

Connection is successful and I can query other basetables like

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
```

It is just that I cannot change to any other schema. I googled and tried all kinds of SET SERACH_PATH and commit it and recreate cursor etc. but no use. I cannot query any other schema.

Comment: Are you sure that your table `mytest` was created in the `public` schema? The default value of the `SEARCH_PATH` parameter is `'$user', public` and if 1) you have schema with the same name as connected user and 2) you created table without specifying the schema name then the table, probably, was created at the schema schema `user1` (from your example) instead of `public`. To find your table: `SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_name ilike 'mytests';` [More details](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_search_path.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I executed SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'mytest';
Results are - table_schema = public & table_name = mytest
So I can confirm it is created under public.

Default schema I see "pg_catalog" for my connection and not public.
I can access all pg_catalog tables.

Comment: And everything Ok with characters cases, your table named exactly `mytests`, not something like `MyTests`?

Comment: Yes! all are in lowercase - SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'mytest'; Table name "mytest" and it has only 2 columns. One is int4 length-10 and the other one is text, if that helps.

Comment: It works for me https://github.com/JamesSjaalman/gigabert/blob/master/hubertc.c (line#133) If it doesn't work for you it could be an amazon-rds -glitch (or something in psycopg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER USER username SET search_path = schema1,schema2;
```

After setting this the query works fine!